# CSS: How to hide Contact Form 7 text labels

Tags: css, contact-form-7

An example Contact Form 7 form is [here](http://vmpersonal.com/contact%20form%207.html).

How do I hide the:

- Name (required)
- Email (required)
- Phone (required)

I have tried:

```
.wpcf7-form p label {display: none;}
.wpcf7-form p label span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {display: block;}
```

but this didn't work.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why don't you remove them in WordPress backed?

Comment: Excellent. I didn't realize you could do that. Thank you.

Comment: Why not giving a complete answer explaining how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide the `label` element in Contact Form 7 you can remove the html element. It won't affect your form's logic.

So, you must have something like this:

```
 <label>
    [email* your-email]
 </label>

 [submit "Submit"]
```

Remove the `label` element and save your form. You must have something like this now:

```
 [email* your-email]

 [submit "Submit"]
```